# iOS - Change text font for each segment in UISegmentController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I got a `UISegmentedControl` called mySegmentedControl

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *mySegmentedControl;
```

with 3 segments, and I would change text font for each segment.. Is possible?

Comment: If you found a better solution then please post here it will help others.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can ----- Try this

```
for(uint i=0;i<[mySegmentedControl subviews].count;i++)
{
    for(UIView *view in [[[mySegmentedControl subviews] objectAtIndex:i] subviews])
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            if(i==0)  // set First segment font
                [(UILabel*)view setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:27]];

            if(i==1)  // set Second segment font
                [(UILabel*)view setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:17]];

            if(i==2)  // set Third segment font
                [(UILabel*)view setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:7]];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He is asking different font for each segment text.

Comment: This may work at one point but it is a very fragile solution.

Comment: Is it possible to set a selected and non selected image for each segment?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. Your only options are either use a custom open source implementation, or set a custom image with the text for each segment.

Comment: Through .xib we can set custom image for each segment.

Comment: It is possible to set a different image for each segment. Look at the docs for `UISegmentedControl`.

Comment: @rmaddy Ahh nice, how could I have missed that? Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any images instead of text. This will give you flexible customization for appearance.

```
NSArray *segemtImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1st.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"2nd.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"3rd.png"], nil];
UISegmentedControl *segmentControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segemtImages];
```

Answer (score 0):

I modify @Anand Natan 's code:
In storyboard set the first label "1111111111111" is to change it default width. Because change the label don't change segmentcontroll size.

```
    for(uint i=0;i<[_menuBarTop subviews].count;i++){
        for(uint j=0;j<[[[[_menuBarTop subviews] objectAtIndex:i] subviews]count];j++){
            UIView* view = [[[_menuBarTop subviews] objectAtIndex:i] subviews][j];
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
                UILabel* label = (UILabel*)view;
                if([label.text isEqualToString:@"1111111111111"]){
                    label.text = LANGLOC(@"videolist_category_choosen");
                }else if([label.text isEqualToString:@"2"]){
                    label.text = LANGLOC(@"videolist_category_followed");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSDictionary *textAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12], NSFontAttributeName, nil];
[_sgmntStatusUI setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

for ios7 later varsions